# This edit should not have been approved

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

[This edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/64644) was well intentioned but obscures the difficulties that the OP is having with the English language.

Sometimes, to get at the heart of a question it is important to remove grammatical errors, even of learners such as this. But in this case we should not have approved the edit because it changes the nature of the question.

> Can I ask "What would he likes to eat?"?

Is a different question to

> Can I ask "What would he like to eat?"?

For the first (if it were migrated to ELL) we could answer about how "what he likes to eat" is different to "what would he like to eat?".

The second does not leave such an avenue open, which is possibly detrimental to the OP.

Answer (score 8):

The question has been migrated to ELL and the invalid edit was rolled back. In the future, if you see an invalid edit you should roll it back with a comment detailing the reason and encourage anyone who disagrees to discuss the issue in chat or meta (as you have done here.)

In the meantime, thanks for pointing out this excellent example of a common "edit trap" on ELU.